# How do I find $m$ so that the given equation will have two different real solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x^2-mx+m+3=0$$

Given the equation above, I have to find $m$ such that the equation will have two different real solutions. I've never seen a problem like this before and would like to be pointed in the right direction as to how I should approach it.

Hints only, please. No actual solution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$ax^2+bx+c=0$ has two different real solutions if and only if $b^2-4ac>0.$

Comment: $b^{ 2 }-4ac>0\quad \Rightarrow \quad m^{ 2 }-4m-12>0\quad \Rightarrow (m-6)(m+2)>0$

Is this going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint2**

correct, both factors should be of the same sign;
or briefly sketch the graph of the function f(m)